# How to reset Gitlab CI/CD shared runner network resources?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My Gitlab CI/CD has been working amazingly to deploy a static site until I changed a jpg file while keeping the filename and so the url the same. The new file is not being reflected in the CI/CD deployed site but I can see the new image in my local build.

My job is being assigned the same shared runner everytime. So I think that maybe network resources are being cached and the build job is always using the older file.

I changed the filename and now I can see it in the CI/CD deployed site as well.

Is there any way to either not use the previously assigned runner or clear the network cache?

Comment: Please clarify your question: what image you refer to, where it is being used, what you get as a result and what you expect.

Comment: Have edited the question.